# How to convert json into RDD[json]

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I want to write json object in spark but when I try to convert it to an RDD using sc.parallelize, it again converts it back to a string

```
import scala.util.parsing.json._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.JsonDSL._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

val df = Seq((2012, 8, "Batman", 9.8), 
             (2012, 9, "Batman", 10.0), 
             (2012, 8, "Hero", 8.7),
             (2012, 10, "Hero", 5.7), 
             (2012, 2, "Robot", 5.5), 
             (2011, 7, "Git", 2.0),
             (2010, 1, "Dom", 2.0),
             (2019, 3, "Sri", 2.0)).toDF("year", "month", "title", "rating")

case class Rating(year:Int, month:Int, title:String, rating:Double)


import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
val ratingList = df.as[Rating].collectAsList

import java.io._
val output = for (c <- ratingList) yield
{
      val json = ("record" ->
              ("year" -> c.year) ~
              ("month" -> c.month) ~
              ("title" -> c.title) ~
              ("rating" -> c.rating))
      compact(render(json))
}

output.foreach(println)
```

At this stage it is a json object, all is well. But when I convert it to an RDD, spark is treating it as a string

```
val outputDF = sc.parallelize(output).toDF("json")
outputDF.show()
outputDF.write.mode("overwrite").json("s3://location/")
```

Output is :

```
{"test":{"json":"{\"record\":{\"year\":2012,\"month\":8,\"title\":\"Batman\",\"rating\":9.8}}"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you call `compact` - you create String out of your rendered json.
See:

```
scala> val json = ("name" -> "joe") ~ ("age" -> 35)
scala> compact(render(json))
res2: String = {"name":"joe","age":35}
```

That means your `output` is a collection of Strings. And when you parallelize it - you get RDD[String].

You probably want to return result of `render` function to get collection of JSON objects. But you need to check documentation for that.

Of-course Spark doesn't know how to convert JSON object from third party library to DataFrame with `toDF()` function. Probably you could do something like:

```
val anotherPeopleRDD = sc.parallelize(
  """{"name":"Yin","address":{"city":"Columbus","state":"Ohio"}}""" :: Nil)
val anotherPeople = sqlContext.read.json(anotherPeopleRDD)
```

So basically have RDD[String] and then read it as JSON.

**And BTW**

Why do you do first this:

```
val ratingList = df.as[Rating].collectAsList
val output = for (c <- ratingList) yield
{
      val json = ("record" ->
              ("year" -> c.year) ~
              ("month" -> c.month) ~
              ("title" -> c.title) ~
              ("rating" -> c.rating))
      compact(render(json))
}
```

And then:

```
val outputDF = sc.parallelize(output).toDF("json")
```

Why don't you just process all your data in cluster like this:

```
df.as[Rating].map{c =>
  val json = ("record" ->
    ("year" -> c.year) ~
      ("month" -> c.month) ~
      ("title" -> c.title) ~
      ("rating" -> c.rating))
  compact(render(json))
}
```

This way it will be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks Vladislav, I got the problem, now I can parallelize my output, but cannot use toDF to write data to a file using spark

Comment: I've extended my answer. Rate and accept is appreciated, btw :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, you have made my day.